# Error obtained with Pyomo/Ipopt when optimizing a customized function

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am newbie in Pyomo and Ipopt. I would like to optimize a nonlinear optimization problem using these tools.I get an error trying to optimize a function.

I have been playing with the examples provided by Pyomo. The main difference in my problem is that I would like to define the objective function in a separate function and that it implies some multiplication with numpy arrays, but I think both of them can be handled with Pyomo.

I have tried to simplify my problem as much as possible (for sure it does not make sense from an optimization point of view but it is just to show the problem). My problem looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *

def myfunc(model, extra_param):
    matrix_A=np.sin(np.random.rand(100,100))+extra_param
    return sum(model.x*matrix_A-extra_param)

extra_param=5
model = ConcreteModel()
model.IDX=range(100)
model.x = Var(model.IDX,bounds=(0,1.), initialize=0.99)
model.obj=Objective(expr = myfunc(model,extra_param))
model.pprint()
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.solve(model, tee=True)
```

and I get the following message:

```
Ipopt 3.11.1: C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\Library\bin\ipopt.exe: jacdim: got M = 0, N = 0, NO = 1
ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
```

Comment: Using a random number generator inside the objective is not something I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your comment. Yes, indeed it does not make sense from an optimization point of view (I substitute some third party data to the random matrix just to simplify the problem). However, I get the same error with and without the random number generator inside the objective function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because your objective function does not return an expression that leads to a scalar value (you can see that by checking the results of `model.obj.pprint()`).

Something like this would probably do what you want:

```
def myfunc(model, extra_param):
    matrix_A=np.sin(np.random.rand(100,1)).flatten() + extra_param
    return sum(matrix_A[i] * model.x[i] for i in model.IDX)
```

Notice that I changed the `(100,100)` part in your `np.random.rand` function with `(100,1)`, since your variable `model.x` is a vector. Additionally, the `.flatten()` method will collapse the array into 1-D.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, very useful! Indeed, I had a dimension problem when I simplified my problem. For my actual problem I need matrix_A to still be a 2D array since the objective function will be such as: obj=sum(vector1+vector2) where each vector results from multiplying such as: vector1(dim n, dim 1)=(matrix(dim n, dim m)*model.x(dim m,dim 1)**2 (power of each element of the array). The same with vector2 but with a different matrix. Should I also try to collapse to a 1D array?

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Your formula makes sense from a mathematical point of view, but just be careful as the Pyomo notation of some multiplications might be different (see e.g. the difference in my `return` statement with yours). Generally, an easy way to check that everything is good is to use the `.pprint()` method on your objective and to see if the Expression there is an actual expression or something else that needs to be corrected (e.g. a Numpy array).